# Unit test framework - TestNG using configurable value to define threadPoolSize

Tags: java, unit-testing, multithreading, tdd, testng

I'm digging little bit the [TestNG](http://testng.or) framework.

I'm using annotations to configure thread values in my test case, example:

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 2, invocationCount = 10)
public void testOne() {
    //some code
}
```

The idea is config these values in a config file and this values should be passed to all tests.

So I need to change these values from a config entry or pass this value through unitTest constructor, but TestNG is only accepting constant values.

Any tips/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "IAnnotationTransformer" interface to make "invocationCount" and "threadPoolSize" parameter values configurable through a .properties file to override default values.

To address this issue, I've created a Sample Example. Please check this out **https://github.com/pashtika/test-ng/tree/master/testng-annotation-configurable**.